# My key mapping appears when I run :map, but when I try to trigger it I get "E492: Not an editor command"

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings

I am learning vim.

I am at a part that I am very excited about because I think it will lead to a lot of productivity gains: key mapping.

I added the following mapping to my `.vimrc`:

```
let mapleader = ","

nnoremap <leader>inc :set incsearch<CR>
```

Then I saved the file, opened a new `vim` file in Vim in a new tab in iTerm, and tried to run the new mapping: I typed `,inc` then <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

The result is:

```
E492: Not an editor command: ,inc
```

When I run `:map`, I see the mapping listed apparently correctly.

So my question is, why might this not be working?

If need be, I can paste my `.vimrc` here.

EDIT: I noticed that in fact the key binding does work but not in command mode as I had erroneously thought. It works in regular normal mode.

Comment: Welcome to Vim :-). If the answer is solving your problem maybe could you validate it (using the green V) to avoid that it popup regularly asking for a valid answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that what you type is `:,inc` and not simply `,inc`

Because of the initial `:` you must the `c` flavour of `map`

```
cnoremap <leader>inc set incsearch<CR>
```